# Adding custom actions to MsTest when test fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, command-line, mstest

I would like to add some custom reporting when in a run of my suites test fails. I.e. I don't want just to have name of the test that failed and owner outputted on the screen (we run tests from cmd) but to query database where we have history of our runs and output history of the given test in order to tell developer is the failure regression and a checkin blocker or it is just a flaky test.

What is the easiest way to achieve this? I can perhaps create a wrapper around mstest and somehow extract result info? or there is an easier way?

Thanks

Comment: Are your tests associated with a Test Case? Do you run your tests via MSTest or are you creating test runs with [TCM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff942470.aspx)?

Comment: Tests are associated with Test Cases. I run tests via MSTest (directly calling MSTest.exe). Thanks.

Comment: This way is not possible. When you run your tests via `MSTest`, the results are only stored in the local test result file (*.trx) created in your pc. You should run them via TCM or by creating `Test Plans` via `Microsoft Test Manager`. Then, the test results will be stored in the TFS database and will be associated with a Test Case, Test Plan, Test Run, Build Number... e.t.c. Once you run them that way, use MTM  or TFS API to get the information you want.

Comment: Perhaps, you should edit your question and ask how you could get the information via Microsoft Test Manager or TFS API so you can get a more detailed answer.